# Twisting 6 feet of solid 14 gauge wire?

Tags: electrical

I need to twist nicely a 6-foot pair of insulated solid electrical wire. It can be 14 gauge or slightly thinner. The insulation can be nylon or PVC. Two wires must be at 90 degrees to each other while being twisted. I’ve tried this by hand, but the result is inconsistent. Is there a tool or technique I could use?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103868/discussion-on-question-by-safesphere-twisting-6-feet-of-solid-14-gauge-wire).

Answer (score 12):

Try an electric drill.  Put the two ends of the wire into the drill chuck; fasten the other ends of the wires to something; step back until the wires are taut, then turn on the drill.  As the wires twist and the cable shortens, you'll have to walk forward to where the wires are anchored.

But I'm not sure if this would work with your "90 degrees to each other" requirement.

Comment: Yes. If you will be doing this often, buy an eye bolt for the drill. The outcome is controlled by indicating the the number of twists per distance (usually inches in the US), sometimes with a tolerance, on the drawing.

Comment: I need a nice even twist at 90 degrees. It doesn’t have to be fast. Doing one turn at a time is fine, as long as I get a consistent result. I doubt a drill would help. It would start loose and then apply more torque at its end.

Comment: If you are worried about uniform twisting, start with extra length and cut off a few feet from each end after you twist.

Comment: @safesphere having twisted many wires of varying thickness together over the years with manual handrills and battery ones, even mains drills then an evenness of twist is possible with practice... You should give it  a go.

Comment: @Mattman944 When I do this by hand, each wire is constantly bending around the other. When one starts bending slightly more than the other, the result becomes uneven. It takes 8 or 9 feet of wire to make a 6-foot pair and 14 gauge is pretty thick. I can try, but I just don’t see how a drill would ensure tight and equal bending of each wire at 90 degrees over such length. I’d prefer some specialized tool where the process can be controlled at the place of twisting feeding the wire there gradually. My budget is $100 give or take.

Comment: @safesphere - What you're asking for is a rather specialized use tool.  I doubt that you'll find anything that meets your needs in that price range.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with perfectly twisted wire?

Comment: @clwhoops44 - "a [twisted pair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twisted_pair) reduces electromagnetic radiation from the pair and crosstalk between neighboring pairs and improves rejection of external electromagnetic interference." 90 degrees is ideal, but shouldn't be completely necessary. Cat5 is more like 45.

Comment: "specialized tool for audiophile voodoo" and "budget" are not compatible concepts!

Comment: @Affe I hear you perfectly well. I have a Master degree in physics and have done enormous experimental research on signal propagation in cables. My goal was to understand what matters and what works, because I couldn’t afford insane audiophile prices. This has paid off. All my connections now are DIY costing peanuts while outperforming fancy commercial products. So budget is compatible with voodoo, but only if you know the secret manic spell :)

Comment: @Mazura Right, but interestingly, twisting in Cat5 or any Ethernet is different for each pair. It is a little known, but easily understood fact that two pairs twisted the same way don’t reject cross-talk between each other. They have to be twisted “relative to each other” (meaning at different angles or with different periods) to reject, so all 4 Ethernet pairs are different. Also twisting of Cat6 seems more tight Than Cat5 while still different for each pair.

Comment: @safesphere ***ALL*** audio connections should cost peanuts.  More robust cables and gold-plated connectors improve cable/connector lifespan, but do not affect the signal in any way whatsoever.  This has been proven, over and over again, by engineers.  The only people who dispute it are "audiophiles" who claim unquantifiable subjective "improvements" without carrying out proper testing.  Properly-run blind testing has been carried out, with these same audiophiles, and the same individuals cannot tell the difference.  TLDR: If you think there's a difference, you're the problem, not the cable.

Comment: @Graham - I wasn't going to go down that rabbit hole, but I'm glad you brought it up.

Comment: @SteveSh Someone always tries saving others from their illusions :)

Comment: Yes you can reduce the wires' RF output but since you spent $$$$$ on your electronics, they have massive input caps to do exactly that for you.

Answer (score 8):

Expanding on @ecnerwal 's answer

This sounds like a rope-making jig, that uses one winder per strand.  Navies use to make their own mooring and rigging ropes using machines like this

[image: From https://maritime.org/doc/luce/part1.htm]

sometimes with a "pingpong bat" paddle to help set the tension in the layup.

[image: From https://www.instructables.com/id/Reuse-old-printer-ribbons-and-video-tape-to-make-r/]

I think you could achieve your goal using two lengths of wire, perhaps 50% longer than the final length you think you require.  Onecordless drill per wire for twisting, a helper to press both triggers, and a clamp for the far end.   You would use some form of paddle to keep the twists apart until sufficient tension is reached, where you slowly move the paddle towards the drills.

This twist will lessen the twist in the remaining sections of wire, so the drills have to add more twists.

Perhaps practice with anything you have around the home already - even long strips of plastic would work as test ropes.

- Have you considered winding an earth wire into your "power-rope" ?
- What about cooling?  twisted wires will get hotter than the same wire untwisted.
- Stranded vs Solid core wire - the solid will take the twist better but will be much harder to work with.

Comment: Also, solid wire may snap if "worked" for a prolonged period. That is, if it's in any unsupported situation where it can move or flex (even just by a small amount), then it may fail in the future. Almost all cables you use on a daily basis are multi-core to avoid this limitation.

Comment: I really like the idea of manufacturing 21st century audiophile juju using 19th century pre-electrical technology. +100 for the illustrations, if I could.

Comment: TKOR had a series of semi-instructional videos on this topic: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ddenqErLL0Q

Comment: @UuDdLrLrSs Very helpful videos. Thanks so much!

Comment: @nigel222 “*I really like the idea of manufacturing 21st century audiophile juju using 19th century pre-electrical technology.*” - Not just using, but making a machine for making cables before making cables. The irony of this is just hilarious! Of course, you can always buy one instead ;) https://www.thecableco.com/cables/power-cables.html?dir=desc&order=price

Comment: This is a helpful answer, thank you! +1. To answer your questions on solid vs. stranded and the ground wire, I will refer to the original source of this design: http://www.empiricalaudio.com/computer-audio/technical-papers/myths-and-snake-oil - Search this page for “Empirically“ and read from there and the next paragraph. I’ve tried 10 and 12 gauge and found them having no benefit over more flexible 14 gauge. Cooling is not needed, because the heat release is negligible.

Comment: @safesphere on the sensible front, descendants of that machine live on for "spinning" datacommunication cables. There is probably interesting epicyclic gearing involved to spin four twisted pairs with four different pitches into one cat-5e or cat-6 cable.

Answer (score 5):

The 90 degree requirement would be most easily achieved by cutting two slots in a board at 90 degrees that allow a slip-fit of the wire, with the intersection point being just off the edge of the board, then screwing another board to it to hold the wires in place.

Given your budget, you'd then be attaching a drill (or a brace/hand crank/speed wrench) and walking away from the board, maintaining tension while twisting.

For precision, you might mount it on a wire wrapping lathe carriage to ensure even feed, but not on your budget.

Comment: I’ve tried this with some success +1. I drilled two holes at 90 degrees in a small piece of wooden board and twisted by hand. It worked well for thicker nylon wire like 12 or 10 gauge, but failed for thinner PVC wire. Perhaps I should try some slippery plastic instead of wood. Twisting at 90 degrees in place while moving along the wire seems a better approach than twisting the whole length at once with a drill hoping to get to 90 degrees and even twist everywhere.